# How to crop Top, Left, Bottom, and Right boundaries in an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, crop, edge-detection

I'm trying to crop the top, left, bottom, and right boundaries of the image below.

[image: Image to Crop]

So, basically, I'm looking to create something that would take the image above as the input and output these images:

[image: North Crop]

[image: West Crop]

[image: South Crop]

[image: East Crop]

The straight lines and their dimensions can be detected using `houghlines` in MATLAB, but how can I find the positions of the convex and concave pieces in the image? I tried using `regionprops` and the `extrema` property, but it would not detect the concave curves (only gave points for the extrema of the convex curves.) I need to find out the lowest/highest points in the concave/convex curves but I'm not sure how to go about that. I have the step after that figured out though; I can easily use `imcrop` to crop out the respective boundaries once I know them.

Comment: Is this your real image? So is your image really black and white? Because if so, it's as simple as finding the intersections of the straight lines, and then finding the last/first white pixel in the corresponding subarrays; no need to resort to feature detection.

Comment: Oh, wow... I would try that, but Divakar's method functioned perfectly. Thanks for the tip; late night coding takes its toll on the mind!

Comment: @user1106340 I guess that's what I did, simple maths, no complicated measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
%%// Tolerance in percentage for the outliers/noise in the image because 
%%// of which the edges are not perfectly vertical or horizontal and 
%%// the ovalish blobs are not "round" enough
f=2;

%%// Read in your image
img = im2bw(imread('patt1.png'));

%%// Main processing
sum1 = sum(img,1);
box_startx = find(sum1>0.33*size(img,1),1);
box_stopx = size(img,2) - find(fliplr(sum1)>0.33*size(img,1),1) + 1;

sum2 = sum(img,2)'; %'
box_starty = find(sum2>0.33*size(img,2),1);
box_stopy = size(img,1) - find(fliplr(sum2)>0.33*size(img,2),1) + 1;

blob_leftx = find(sum1>(1-0.01*f)*max(sum1),1);
blob_rightx = size(img,2) - find(fliplr(sum1)>(1-0.01*f)*max(sum1),1) + 1;

blob_topy = find(sum2>(1-0.01*f)*max(sum2),1);
blob_bottomy = size(img,1) - find(fliplr(sum2)>(1-0.01*f)*max(sum2),1) + 1;

top1 = img(1:blob_topy,box_startx+1:box_stopx);
left1 = img(box_starty:box_stopy-1,1:blob_leftx);
bottom1 = img(blob_bottomy:end,box_startx:box_stopx);
right1 = img(box_starty:box_stopy,blob_rightx:end);

%// Debug
figure,
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(top1)
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(bottom1)
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(left1)
subplot(2,2,4);imshow(right1)
```

**Output**

[image]